# Make Zoho CRM extension using Angular

Tags: crm, zoho

I am looking for ways to work with Angular for a Zoho extension project.

In the Zoho community, I saw [a comment](https://help.zoho.com/portal/en/community/topic/extension-developers) where such a possibility is maintained.
[image]

But nothing further can be found anywhere. The project structures created by Angular CLI and ZET CLI seem to have some commonalities. Has anyone worked in a Zoho CRM extension or a Zoho extension before,using Angular?

*NOTE: I do not mean using the Zoho APIs to communicate with Zoho from Angular. I mean an Angular Project that can be used to build an extension in Zoho.*

**EDIT:
What I have tried so far is to create two separate projects:
**Cat Zoho Project** &
**Cat Angular Project**.
I write all the code in Cat Angular Project and build it. I copy the contents of the Angular build and paste them in the 'app' directory of the Cat Zoho Project. I validate the package and pack it using the ZET CLI. The zipped package is then pasted in the Connected Apps section of the extension in Zoho. But when I locally serve the Zoho project (zet run), nothing is displayed at all. No idea what I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a specific question here, will try to give a general overview of the process. I haven't worked with a extension using Angular, however have created VueJS based CRM extensions among others.

**Project Setup**

The `zet` tools looks for a `app` directory with source files and a `plugin-manifest.json` file in the root directory with the target Zoho service mentioned in it. So instead of creating two separate projects, set the target directory of the angular to `app/` directory instead of `dist/` and add the `plugin-manifest.json` file.

*plugin-manifest.json*

```json
{
  "service": "CRM"
}
```

**Testing**

Before uploading the application to Sigma, you can check whether the widget works by configuring the hosting of widget to *external* and pointing the local server URL in there. So you can run `ng serve` and set the URL in Zoho widget as http://localhost:4200/.

**Build**

Once it is ready, you can build the angular project and verify that the output is in the `app/` directory. Then running `zet pack` would produce a zip file from the `app/` directory which can be uploaded to the target Zoho service